# golang type []dao.Record has no field or method Id

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to access `Features`.`Id` of a struct using the following condition.

```
Record, _ := s.Dao.GetFeatPlansById(QueryId)
if Record.Features.Id == 0 { // <-- error here
    // Do something
}
```

The `Record` has the following struct

```
type Record struct {
    Id       int
    Name     string
    Features []*Feature
}


// The following Feature struct is located on another file
type Feature struct {
    Id            int
    Name          string
}
```

However, golang is returning the following error message

```
Record.Features.Id undefined (type []*dao.Feature has no field or method Id) compiler
```

How can we access `Features`.`Id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would answer my question based on feedbacks I received.

What I did was to access the slice and just get the first index from what I need.

```
feature := Record.Features[0]
    if feature.Id == 0 {
        Record.Features = nil
    }
```